# HMAC Digest node.js crypto

Tags: node.js, cryptography, hex, hmac, node-crypto

Can anyone help me with this problem please.

I am trying to use the follwing code to generate a HMAC digest, but crypto module in node doesnt appear to return the correct signature?

```
var ipnStr = 'b2b3493a-ef96-4eea-853e-3fd82491a4100.00241BTCCOMPLETED';
var secret = 'lB6E2Um6hitYosCd4J9zTNBZKcKHLiJvGqfab4VKh0E';
var signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret).update(ipnStr).digest('hex');
```

Signtaure should return:

```
7184c8edefa057d6c25bf750db4652dd261e36c350f2a17c410c24524ea210f1
```

But Im getting a completely different string, it works on the follwing website:

http://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html

Any ideas?  Am I missing something?

Thanks.

*** UPDATE ***

I have solved the issue, turns out I was generating the secret incorrectly and I am now getting the correct signature.

Comment: What version of node are you using? Tested on v0.10.28 and it works fine.

Comment: I am using version v0.10.31 of node.